# Applying And to a list inside a Function

Tags: evaluation, code-generation, meta-programming

`And` has `HoldAll` attribute and test its argument by sequence. But doing `And@@{}` will lost this advantage and slow down the code. Now I have a pure function

```
And @@ (PrimeQ[# + {1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27}]) &
```

and I want it expand to

```
PrimeQ[# + 1] && PrimeQ[# + 3] && PrimeQ[# + 7] && PrimeQ[# + 9] && 
  PrimeQ[# + 13] && PrimeQ[# + 27] &
```

to make use of the property of `And`. Currently I have

```
Evaluate[And @@ 
    Function[u, h[u], Listable][# + {1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27}]] & /. 
 h -> PrimeQ
```

But it looks counter intuitive. Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Look at `AllTrue` and see if it is to your liking.

Comment: Using `AllTrue` : `AllTrue[# + {1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27}, PrimeQ] &`

Comment: Thanks rcollyer and JHM it worked for this case, but I also want to know what I should do when generally it is a list

Comment: You could do something like: `AllTrue[Outer[Plus, #, {1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27}], PrimeQ, 2] &`

Answer (score 3):

For the exact expansion that you show:

```
Replace[And[1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27] &, x_ :> PrimeQ[# + x], {2}]
```

> ```
> PrimeQ[#1 + 1] && PrimeQ[#1 + 3] && PrimeQ[#1 + 7] &&
>  PrimeQ[#1 + 9] && PrimeQ[#1 + 13] && PrimeQ[#1 + 27] &
> ```

Or if you have an external list:

```
list = {1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27};

With[{a = list},
  And @@@ Replace[a &, x_ :> PrimeQ[# + x], {2}]
]
```

> ```
> PrimeQ[#1 + 1] && PrimeQ[#1 + 3] && PrimeQ[#1 + 7] &&
>  PrimeQ[#1 + 9] && PrimeQ[#1 + 13] && PrimeQ[#1 + 27] &
> ```

Other approaches:

```
And @@@ Function @@ {PrimeQ /@ Hold @@ (# + list)}

PrimeQ /@ Hold @@ (# + list) /. _[x__] :> (And[x] &)
```

If sequential evaluation by other means is acceptable then also consider:

```
x \[Function] PrimeQ[x + #] & /@ And[1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27];
```

As noted in the comments [`AllTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html), introduced in v10.0, provides a clean approach:

```
AllTrue[# + {1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27}, PrimeQ] &    (* JungHwan Min *)
```

If you wish to prevent even the summation before testing:

```
x \[Function] AllTrue[{1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 27}, PrimeQ[x + #] &]
```