# And@@(f/@list) without evaluating f for the whole list

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

`And[f[1],f[2]]` doesn't evaluate `f[2]` if `f[1]` is false, but `And@@{f[1],f[2]}` does.

How do I evaluate `And@@(f/@list)`, or `Or@@(f/@list)` for that matter, without evaluating more than necessary of `f/@list`?

Comment: `AllTrue[list, f]` ?

Comment: Related: [(124534)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124534/121)

Comment: `AllTrue` is cleaner, but for reference: `And @@ f /@ Hold @@ list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `Block`?:

```
f[a_] := a < 2
lst = Range[5]
Block[{f}, And @@ f /@ lst]
```

If you already have the **explicit** list at hand, you can simply use `Unevaluated`:

```
And @@ Unevaluated @ {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5]}
```

---

If you don't even want to generate the expression `And[f[1], f[2], …]` in intermediate step, then I think it's better to avoid `And`:

```
Catch[If[! f @ #, Throw @ False] & /@ lst; True]
```

Similarly, `Or @@ f /@ lst` can be implemented as

```
Catch[If[f @ #, Throw @ True] & /@ lst; False]
```

---

For completeness, as mentioned by [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) and [Blrp](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/25171/blrp), `AllTrue` and `AnyTrue` seems to be the best choice since *v10.0*.

A simple test for all the methods under this question:

```
f[a_] := a < 250000
f2 = # < 250000 &;
lst = Range[500000];

Block[{f}, And @@ f /@ lst] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.29, False} *)
Block[{f}, And @@ f2 /@ lst] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.290, False} *)

Catch[If[! f @ #, Throw @ False] & /@ lst; True] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.488, False} *)
Catch[If[! f2@ #, Throw @ False] & /@ lst; True] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.4785, False} *)

Catch[Scan[If[! f @ #, Throw @ False] &, lst]; True] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.3554, False} *)
Catch[Scan[If[! f2 @ #, Throw @ False] &, lst]; True] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.352, False} *)

And @@ f /@ Hold @@ lst // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.231, False} *)
And @@ f2 /@ Hold @@ lst // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.194, False} *)

AllTrue[lst,f] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.165, False} *)
AllTrue[lst,f2] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.13, False} *)
```

Tested on *v12.1.0*. (Wolfram cloud, Android app. )

Comment: ilian's suggestion of `AllTrue` is another way, and most convenient in some circumstances such as built-in functions and unassigned pure functions. Add it, as well as `AnyTrue`, and I'll accept.

Comment: @Blrp Added as requested.

Comment: Wair, 12.1 is out?! Why there was no blog post about it?

Comment: @victor Seems that the new version is always released a bit earlier silently on Wolfram cloud. The blog post is coming soon, I believe.

Comment: @xzczd that's cool - you can already browse the list of new feature etc. https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn121.html

Comment: In the `Ctach[Map[...]]` construct, use `Scan` instead of `Map` as it doesn't generate the intermediate `List` like `Map`.

Comment: @rcollyer I used `Map` just for compactness, and didn't expect the generation of output slows down the code that much. Edited. Thx for the reminding.

Comment: @xzczd truthfully, I was a little shocked that both `AllTrue` and `And @@ f /@ Hold @@ lst` did as well as they did. But, yes, the generation of the output does incur a cost, so avoid it if you don't need it. Also, as an added bonus, `Scan` does perform the same function compilation that `Map` does for longer inputs.